# Laravel form model binding htmlentities error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use form model binding (which i just learned about), but im following an example from laravel website and one from laracasts. So can someone please educate me?

My View:

```
{{ Form::model($transaction, array(
        'method' => 'PATCH',
        'route' => array('my.transactions.update', $transaction->id)
)) }}
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="date"></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
    {{ Form::text('date', array('class'=>'form-control input-md', 'placeholder'=>'YYYY-MM-DD')); }}
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
{{Form::close() }}
```

My Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $title = "Edit Transaction";
    $transaction = Portfolio::find($this->portfolio_id)->transactions->find($id);
    return View::make('Transactions/edit', compact('title', 'transaction'));
}
```

i dont know whats wrong but i keep getting this error.

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: ../transactions/edit.blade.php)
```

Comment: Please show `transactions/edit.blade.php`.

Comment: That's what the first line is.. It's the line causing the error.

Comment: I am interested in seeing the source of `views/transactions/edit.blade.php`.

Comment: Your `$transaction` in the controller doesn't look right. Try something like `$transaction = Transaction::find($id);` for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option you put as '' can be filled in as Input::old('date')  That way, when you pass old data back to the form let's say when the form isn't completed, the form fields that you specify with the Input::old will be "refilled" with the data they previously completed

{{ Form::text('date', Input::old('date'), $dateOptions) }}

$dateOptions will be your array with the placeholder, id, or any other html attributes you wish to supply.

Hope this helps, even after you figure it out 
Keenan :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It ws actually completely different. But im not sure why...

Problem Line:

```
{{ Form::text('date', array('class'=>'form-control input-md', 'placeholder'=>'YYYY-MM-DD')); }}
```

Correction:

```
{{ Form::text('date', '', array('class'=>'form-control input-md', 'placeholder'=>'YYYY-MM-DD')); }}
```

Comment: You can't skip the middle parameter (default form value). The parameters of Form::text are as follows:
string  $name,
string  $value = null,
array   $options = array()

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php